# What is centripetal force accelerating at any instant if the velocity is already in the correct direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, vectors, velocity

I know centripetal acceleration changes the velocity direction but if we observe any instant in time the velocity does not need to be changed.

Comment: Does [Object moving in a circular path without accelerating](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177096/37364) speak to what your are asking?

Comment: No. I think a train is being deflected not unlike a billiard ball bouncing off of a side rail.

Comment: Centripetal acceleration is the total acceleration when motion is circular at uniform speed. In that case, the velocity is always changing direction. What do you mean when you say the velocity is already in the correct direction?

Comment: At any instant the acceleration has successfully changed the direction. Correct? Then why does it exist at that instant?

Comment: Perhaps "has successfully changed" the direction is the problem. When an object is accelerating, the velocity is always changing. Sometimes the speed is changing and sometimes the direction. Think of Earth orbiting the Sun because of the Sun's gravity. Gravity never stops pulling on the Earth and continually changes its direction. If it did somehow stop, Earth would go in a straight line.

Comment: Have you studied calculus yet? This information might help someone explain things in an understandable way.

Answer (score 0):

Centripetal acceleration and its relation to tangential velocity can only be understood by means of vectors:

[image: Centripetal]

$\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity vector and $\mathbf{a_c}$ the centripetal acceleration vector. They are related by:

$$\mathbf{a_c}=\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{v}}{\text{d}t}$$

So even if $\mathbf{v}$ does not change in **magnitude**, $\mathbf{a_c}$ always exists because the velocity vector's **direction** constantly changes in time.

Comment: But the velocity and acceleration are always perpendicular. If the acceleration changes the velocity direction then at some instant in time they will not be perpendicular but we know they always are.

Comment: @Nectac, $by$ $definition$, the velocity vector is always perpendicular to the acceleration vector when circular motion is seen, and the acceleration vector always points towards the center of the circle.

Comment: @G.Smith Corrected, tank you.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration is not something that makes the velocity changes, it is the change of velocity with time itself. And velocity being a vector, acceleration can be non zero even if the modulus of the velocity is constant.

Until now it is only a definition. But of course there is the physical effect that spinning a weight linked to our hands by a rope, we feel a force. Or, generalizing a little more: a rotating object develops a tensile stress along the direction from the center of rotation outward.

When an object is being pulled (or pushed) linearly, it is intuitive to think of the force as the cause of the (linear) acceleration. But in the rotating movement, it is more like the acceleration causes a force. An object can be sppining forever in the outer space, without applied forces, and there are permanent internal stresses as a consequence.